# Mysql service status

Tags: mysql

I recently was trying to restart MySQL when I ran into an error where it was hanging at "MySQL stop/waiting" I then went to uninstall MySQL, but even with mysql-server and mysql-client uninstalled I still get "MySQL stop/waiting" status. How can I completely remove MySQL?

Comment: Have you checked the MySQL log files to see if they contain anything that might help?

Comment: Looking at the log but don't see anything. The last recorded record was it shutting down. But by running "Sudo service mysql status" It still says "mysql stop/waiting"

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove MySQL, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```